# In Objective-C Check an array of Integer Values and see if at least ONE is > 0

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, cocoa-touch, if-statement

I asked a similar question to test an Array of Bool values [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18619419/in-objective-c-check-an-array-of-boolean-values-and-see-if-at-least-one-is-yes) but now I have changed it so the values are now Integer values and I want to see if any of them are positive.

Example, I add 10 new objects in a loop like below, then at some point some may change and then I need to do a test.  It may be that I do not use NSNumber, as long as I cna get an int out of it.

```
// I create an array like
NSMutableArray *MyArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int count = 0; count < 10; count++)
{
    [MyArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
}


// At some point I change a value or two
[MyArray replaceObjectAtIndex:3 withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5]];
....
....
....
....
[MyArray replaceObjectAtIndex:3 withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:7]];


if([MyArray containsPositiveObject])
{
    // Get the integer
    int MyValue = [MyArray[4]integerValue];

}
```

EDIT

I have tried this and it works but wondered if there was a faster method.

```
if([self containsPositiveValue:selectedItems]) 
{
     // Do my stuff
}
```

And then

```
-(bool)containsPositiveValue:(NSArray *)numberArray
{
    bool result = NO;

    for (NSNumber *obj in numberArray)
    {
        if([obj integerValue])
        {
            result = YES;
            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're trying to do here. Are you trying to implement -containsPositiveObject? If so, what have you already tried?

Comment: @RyanR Okay should have indicated that "containsPositiveObject" is pseudo code and is just what I am trying to get to.  It is looking like I just need to do the loop as other say!  I just wondered if there was a faster method.

Comment: Really -3 for simply question, was it that bad?

Comment: The -3 is almost certainly because you didn't show any attempt at solving this yourself.

Comment: Apart from the facts that bool should be BOOL, that if ([obj integerValue]) is a horrible way to check that the integerValue is not zero instead of checking that it is positive, and apart from the fact that you made this an instance method of a random class when it should be in an NSArray category, it's fine. It should also be called containsPositiveInteger, since @0.1 for example is a positive number but won't be recognised.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
NSArray *array = @[ @(-1) , @(-3) , @(0) , @(-4) , @(2) , @(-1) ];  // zero is not positvie or negitive

NSArray *newArray = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate: [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    return ( [evaluatedObject isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]] && ([evaluatedObject integerValue] > 0) );
    return NO;
}]];

if (newArray.count)
{
    NSLog(@"There are positive values");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"There are no positive values") ;
}
```

Comment: Just write the friggin loop!  It's guaranteed to be faster and simpler than using a predicate.

Answer (score 0):

Surely the simplest way would be to go:

```
NSArray * array = @[@(-1), @(-5), @(-5)];

for (NSNumber * number in array) {

    if (number.intValue > 0) {
        NSLog(@"Positive Values");

        // Add custom code here            

        break;
    }
}
```

This will then check if at least one item in the array is greater than zero and custom code can then be implemented.

I suppose it depends if you want to perform something if there are no positive values and something different if there is?

You could always add something like this:

```
NSArray * array = @[@(-1), @(-5), @(-5)];

NSInteger largestValue = 0;

for (NSNumber * number in array) {

    if (number.intValue > largestValue) {

        largestValue = number.intValue;
    }

    if (largestValue > 0) {
        break; 
    }    
}

if (largestValue > 0) {
    NSLog(@"Positive Value");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"All Negative Values");
}
```

Anyway it gets more complicated the more complicated you want it to work but it should be incredibly simple